# Python3 __requires__ fails in odd way

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, virtualenv, scanpy

Python dogma is that virtualenv's should be used to keep different versions of the same packages apart.  In most other programming contexts this is not a problem.  For instance in linux all sorts of different versions of dynamic libraries can be colocated in /usr/lib64 and the loader has no problem picking out the right one for a binary.

Python does provide a mechanism for picking up only the desired versions.  So I have been trying to keep multiple python package versions in one place.   That means packages need to be wrapped up like this to load the right versions:

```
python3
__requires__ = ['scipy <1.3.0,>=1.2.0', 'anndata <0.6.20', 'loompy <3.0.0,>=2.00', 'h5py <2.10', ]
import pkg_resources
import scipy
print(scipy.__version__)
import anndata
print(anndata.__version__)
import loompy
print(loompy.__version__)
import h5py
print(h5py.__version__)
import scanpy
print(scanpy.__version__)
quit()

#emits

 python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Nov 21 2019, 19:31:34) 
[GCC 8.3.1 20190507 (Red Hat 8.3.1-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> __requires__ = ['scipy <1.3.0,>=1.2.0', 'anndata <0.6.20', 'loompy <3.0.0,>=2.00', 'h5py <2.10']
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> import scipy
>>> print(scipy.__version__)
1.2.3
>>> import anndata
/home/common/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anndata-0.6.19-py3.6.egg/anndata/base.py:17: FutureWarning: pandas.core.index is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.  The public classes are available in the top-level namespace.
  from pandas.core.index import RangeIndex
>>> print(anndata.__version__)
0.6.19
>>> import loompy
>>> print(loompy.__version__)
2.0.17
>>> import h5py
>>> print(h5py.__version__)
2.9.0
>>> import scanpy
>>> print(scanpy.__version__)
1.4.3
```

So far so good.  However if the requires line is changed to:

```
__requires__ = ['scipy <1.3.0,>=1.2.0', 'anndata <0.6.20', 'loompy <3.0.0,>=2.00', 'h5py <2.10', 'scanpy <1.4.4,>=1.4.2']
```

then it all completely falls apart.  The start of the run becomes instead:

```
python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Nov 21 2019, 19:31:34) 
[GCC 8.3.1 20190507 (Red Hat 8.3.1-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> __requires__ = ['scipy <1.3.0,>=1.2.0', 'anndata <0.6.20', 'loompy <3.0.0,>=2.00', 'h5py <2.10', 'scanpy <1.4.4,>=1.4.2']
>>> import pkg_resources
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/common/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 584, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/common/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 901, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/common/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (scanpy 1.5.1 (/home/common/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('scanpy<1.4.4,>=1.4.2'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/common/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3261, in <module>
        @_call_aside
      File "/usr/common/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3245, in _call_aside
        f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/common/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3274, in _initialize_master_working_set
        working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
      File "/usr/common/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 586, in _build_master
        return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
      File "/usr/common/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 599, in _build_from_requirements
        dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
      File "/usr/common/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
        raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (scipy 1.2.3 (/home/common/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy-1.2.3-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg), Requirement.parse('scipy>=1.3.1'), {'umap-learn'})
    >>> import scipy
    >>> print(scipy.__version__)
    1.4.1
    # and numerous other issues
```

This is very strange because when no limitation was set for scanpy the desired version loaded, but when one was set it choked on 1.5.1.

Why does the extra constraint break everything???

Versions of these packages which are present are

```
anndata
anndata-0.6.19.dist-info
anndata-0.6.19-py3.6.egg
anndata-0.7.1.dist-info
anndata-0.7.3.dist-info
scipy
scipy-1.2.3.dist-info
scipy-1.2.3-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg
scipy-1.4.1.dist-info
loompy
loompy-2.0.17.dist-info
loompy-2.0.17-py3.6.egg
loompy-3.0.6.dist-info
h5py
h5py-2.10.0.dist-info
h5py-2.9.0.dist-info
h5py-2.9.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg
scanpy
scanpy-1.4.3.dist-info
scanpy-1.4.3-py3.6.egg
scanpy-1.4.6.dist-info
scanpy-1.5.1.dist-info
scanpy-1.5.2.dev7+ge33a2f33-py3.6.egg
```

This is actually on CentOS, not Red Hat, but that is probably irrelevant.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that `__requires__` is meant to do what you say. Could you link to a source that says that?

Comment: Whether or not it is meant to do so it did not, so I gave up on this approach.  Instead a small software package was written which allows independent python package installation via venv's with subsequent sharing of the common files with soft links and position independent usage of the resulting scripts/programs after they are migrated to a normal linux environment.  See https://sourceforge.net/projects/python-devirtualizer/

Comment: out of curiosity - why do you use both "import pkg_resources" and again import the packages themselves?

Comment: I don't recall specifically why I did that, but I suspect it was because the first import was failing, and the import by package name would always complete.  I believe the second import would do nothing if the package was already imported, so it was a way to always have the following print statements complete even if the first import failed.